# Get text from previous td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that, when clicked, builds a simple table dynamically. In the second `td`, a button is inserted along with some text.

```html
<input type = "button" id = "search" value = "Search">
<div id = "searcharea"></div>
```

```js
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    $('#searcharea').html('<table id = "myTable"><tr><td>Some Text</td><td>Blah Blah<br>Blah Blah<br><input type = "button" value = "Get Text"></td></tr></table>');
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the text from the previous `td` when the "Get Text" button is clicked. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'input', function (event) {
    var prevCell = $(this).closest('td').previous('td').text();
    alert(preCell);
 });
```

I think the answer is a simple one, but I'm not seeing it. Help. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/nguja669/17/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you intended to use jQuery's [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method.

Also, since your table is dynamically generated, it may not exist in the DOM at the time the JavaScript is executed. You can [delegate your click event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) by binding it to a different (parental and static) element instead of the dynamic table.

Below, I've bound the event to the `document` itself, but you can use a more specific element if one exists.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myTable input', function (event) {
    var prevCell = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
    alert(prevCell);
}
```

Test below:

```js
$('#search').on('click', function() {
  $('#searcharea').html('<table id = "myTable"><tr><td>Some Text</td><td>Blah Blah<br>Blah Blah<br><input type = "button" value = "Play"></td></tr></table>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#myTable input', function(event) {
  var prevCell = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
  alert(prevCell);
});
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0.917em;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#myTable td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
<div id="searcharea"></div>
```

Comment: Huge thanks. I think I get it. So, the table isn't in the DOM by the time I click the 'get text' button?

Comment: It is, but the event binding happens before that and the table is not in the DOM at that time. Notice that in [somethingsthere's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386659/get-text-from-previous-td/27386819#answer-27386780), binding is done at the time you click "search". At that point, the DOM is loaded and the binding works fine. The problem I see with that method is that many redundant listeners could be bound, one for each time you click "search". You only need one delegated binding.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here: the moment you bind (`on`) your click, and the way you get the text. Because you are trying to bind at the same time you are binding the click on `#search`, no buttons inside the table exist and therefore don't get bound. Future buttons will have to be bound after creation, so you need to do it after `html()` inserting.

The following works:

```
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    $('#searcharea').html('<table id="myTable"><tr><td>Some Text</td><td>Blah Blah<br>Blah Blah<br><input type="button" value="Play"></td></tr></table>');
    // You need to tie your click to the input here, as the input didn't exist before.
    $('#myTable input').on('click', function (event) {
        // You need to look for the parents, then use the prev() function, not previous().
        var prevCell = $(this).parents('td').prev().text();
        alert(prevCell);
    });
});
```

```js
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    $('#searcharea').html('<table id="myTable"><tr><td>Some Text</td><td>Blah Blah<br>Blah Blah<br><input type="button" value="Play"></td></tr></table>');
    // You need to tie your click to the input here, as the input didn't exist before.
    $('#myTable input').on('click', function (event) {
        // You need to look for the parents, then use the prev() function, not previous.
        var prevCell = $(this).parents('td').prev().text();
        alert(prevCell);
    });
});
```

```css
#myTable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-size: 0.917em;
    width:400px;
    min-width:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#myTable td {
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:6px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "button" id = "search" value = "Search">
    <div id = "searcharea"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Good to see a slightly different way to doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should delegate the handler to a *static* element (*an element which is not being generated, unlike `#myTable`*)so that [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method works with dynamically generated contents inside it. Also, use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) instead of previous:

```
$('#searcharea').on('click', ':button', function (event) {
  var prevCell = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
  alert(preCell);
});
```

Comment: Got it. So I can bind it to any previously constructed element in the document. I didn't know that. Still learning.

Comment: @MatthewMoon Yep.. it'll hold the event handler... when a matching event bubbles upto it, it'll check whether the `event.target` matches the specified selector, if so, it'll fire the callback...

Answer (score 0):

In this case your table doesn't exist when you try to bind the click event to it. So we fix that first. Then we change previous() to prev() and we have it working!

```
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    $('#searcharea').html('<table id = "myTable"><tr><td>Some Text</td><td>Blah Blah<br>Blah Blah<br><input type = "button" value = "Play"></td></tr></table>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#myTable input', function (event) {
    var prevCell = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
    alert(prevCell);
});
```

Comment: Same answers were posted almost 10 minutes ago. What *additional value* does your answer provide..?

Comment: Because now the event is bound to the document rather than to a specific element, @somethinghere . If I were to add another element with the id of my table after this, it would also be triggered by this click event. It's the same as the event delegation in your example, just with a different target.

Comment: @TJ I just typed it up after poking around in the fiddle and hit post. I didn't see all the other answers. Relax.

Comment: Yes, now it is being binded to document. Isn't this a copy paste of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27386819/2333214)..?

Comment: Of course not. We just had very similar answers. It's not like this is rocket surgery here, there's a pretty clear solution.

Comment: Thanks! All answers were great.